# Why doesn't the_tags( ) accept empty string for first argument?

Tags: tags

Why doesn't `the_tags( )` accept empty string for first argument?

It accepts this: `the_tags( 'Text: ', ', ', '' )`
But not this: `the_tags( ' ', ', ', '' )`

Comment: You’re not supposed to use variables like that. It should be just `the_tags( '', ', ', '' )`.

Comment: You will get details info about Tags. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/